# How can agents save path links while moving and know they have reached other different breed agents?

Tags: netlogo

I have two breeds: walkers (dynamic) and events (static).
The walkers move following links (streets) and turning corners at random. 
Events are placed at random over some unknown nodes.

How can each agent know the path he has followed until reaching one event? 
I was wondering if is possible to save it in a list or even a matrix where each row is a path followed to find a different event, but I do not know how to collect these nodes/links.

If a walker finds an event how can he note it and how can save that data?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modification to the 'link-walking turtles' code example in the models library where walkers now have a path variable. When a walker moves to the the next node, it places the new node at the end of the list using `lput`. It will be up to you to manage or clear this list once it reaches an "event" in your model. You might also want to modify this approach to store multiple paths instead of a single path.

```
breed [nodes node]
breed [walkers walker]

walkers-own [
    location  
    path      ;  <-- add a path variable
]  

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape nodes "circle"
  ;; create a random network
  create-nodes 30 [ set color blue ]
  ask nodes [ create-link-with one-of other nodes ]
  ;; lay it out so links are not overlapping
  repeat 500 [ layout ]
  ;; leave space around the edges
  ask nodes [ setxy 0.95 * xcor 0.95 * ycor ]
  ;; put some "walker" turtles on the network
  create-walkers 1 [
    set color red
    set location one-of nodes
    move-to location
    set path (list location)   ; <--  setup a path with the first node
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to layout
  layout-spring nodes links 0.5 2 1
end

to go
  ask links [ set thickness 0 ]
  ask walkers [
    let new-location one-of [link-neighbors] of location
    ;; change the thickness of the link I just crossed over
    ask [link-with new-location] of location [ set thickness 0.5 ]
    face new-location  
    move-to new-location
    set location new-location
    set path lput location path  ; <---  add node to end of path list
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my model walkers move using intermediate steps between nodes so the walker should note/know when he has reach a node and make lput when that happen. I would also appreciate very much with the other breed identification agent. How the walker knows he has find an event?

Comment: check out the `turtles-here` primitive. With your breeds, you could use `nodes-here` or `events-here` to see if either a node or event is in the same patch as your walker. You can check their `distance` for greater precision.